# Will there be a concept for arithmetic types in C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, std, c++20, c++-concepts

I've been looking through concepts library on [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) and i couldn't find a concept for arithmetic types. I couldn't also find it in [p0898](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0898r3.pdf). I think such concept would be very helpful.
Insted of doing:

```
template <typename T>
T some_function(T arg) requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
{ /* functions body */ }
```

I could just do:

```
template <std::arithmetic T>
T some_function(T arg)
{ /* functions body */ }
```

I could obviously define it myself and it wouldn't be hard (ex. `template <typename T> concept arithmetic = std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;`), but in my opinion such basic concept should be defined in standard library. Is there any good reason why it's not there? Or is there any proposal to add it?

Comment: Seems like an oversight since [`std::is_arithmetic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) exists.  You can use that to write your own concept.

Comment: With this way of thinking we could say that we don't need any concept because most of concepts defined in <concepts> header have their integral_constant version in <type_traits> and some are even implemented using them. But integral_constant and a concept are totally different things and integral_constant can't be used as a concept in template parameter list.

Comment: Plus defining arithmetic concept with `std::is_arithmetic_v` instead of concepts `std::integral` and `std:floating_point` would cause compiler to not view these concepts as more constrained versions of arithmetic concept. It is described on [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Atomic_constraints)

Comment: Sorry for the edit, that was a mistake. Something something, concepts should have their own case, something something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any good reason why it's not there? Or is there any proposal to add it?

There isn't any proposal to add it, but I would expect to see an NB comment that just proposes `template <typename T> concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;`<sup>†</sup> (which doesn't guarantee that C++20 will have this concept, merely that at least it will be considered).

The standard library concepts were added by the Ranges proposal and were driven by needs in algorithms for certain concepts. `integral` comes up a lot, but I guess `arithmetic` never did and so it just never got added. If you look at, say, [N4382](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4382.pdf) (from early 2015), you can see that `Integral` (and `SignedIntegral` and `UnsignedIntegral`) were there from the very beginning... whereas even `FloatingPoint` got added way later. (by [P0631](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0631r8.pdf), in July 2019... and even the paper that added the floating point concept didn't make any mention of `arithmetic`)

---

<sup>†</sup>Of course, then you get into the fun question of whether it should be based on strictly that type trait or should it be `template <typename T> concept arithmetic = integral<T> || floating_point<T>;` so that both the `integral` and `floating_point` concepts subsume `arithmetic`. Probably? Maybe?

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm not a C++ expert, and not deeply familiar with C++ concepts. So the following answer *might* be a bit derailing, but I thought about this concept in a different context, and think that some of the points here may be relevant.</sup>

You did not exactly say what the concept should convey, beyond the example that it should cover integral and floating point types. But from a more theoretical, conceptual point of view, "arithmetics" could be applied much more broadly - even though the word *arithmetics* implies that it is about *numbers*.

Intuitively, one could expect the concept to convey the following:

The type in question supports the basic arithmetic operations, `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, and the result type of these operations is the same as the type of the operands. From a quick websearch, this idea seems to be formalized roughly like that:

```
self operator+(self const& x, self const& y);
self operator−(self const& x, self const& y);
self operator∗(self const& x, self const& y);
self operator/(self const& x, self const& y);
```

However, there is more that is required for a proper arithmetic:

- the there must be a closure of the elements under the given operation
- there must be a neutral element of addition (`0`)
- there must be a neutral element of multiplication (`1`)
- there must be an additive inverse for each element (`-x`)
- there must be a multiplicative inverse for each element (`/x` - except for the neutral element of addition...)

You see that a can of worms is opened here. These constraints are already hard or impossible to enforce for integral types, as there may be no additive inverse, particularly for `unsigned` types. For floating point types, the special cases grow out of hand quickly, due to `+/-inf` and most importantly: `NaN`. All this does not yet even *consider* the limited precision of floating point arithmetic.

---

Going one step further down the theoretical rabbit hole: The concept of arithmetics should probably be a special form (or combination) of general *algebraic* concepts. For example, it is perfectly fine to consider the unsigned integer types as a cyclic [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), and to some extent, some structures involving integral or floating point types have properties that would be associated with a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

---

So a concept of arithmetics that goes beyond saying that it is "either float or int" would certainly be interesting, but has many caveats. Trying to formulate the concept cleanly, so that it may, for example, also be applied to *complex numbers* or similar structures, is difficult. And *if* one tried to define this, one would certainly also like to cover other algebraic structures like groups or rings (e.g. for matrices or polynomials) or even [vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)...

Some people *tried* this, at least: A quick websearch revealed a [Techcnical Report: Fundamental Algebraic Concepts in Concept-Enabled C++](ftp://jcmc.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR638.pdf) that tackles some of these ideas, including arithmetics, and points out the difficulties that are associated with that. It's from 2006, though - there might be newer research, based on the concepts as they found their way into the standard.

Comment: Additive inverses for unsigned types are perfectly defined, unlike those for signed types. The requirement of multiplicative inverse automatically discards integral types (they are mostly 2^n-based, and FWIW the Standard does not specify the exact cardinals).

Comment: @bipll True, for the usual unsigned types in C++, the additive inverse really is *defined* (as in "**not** undefined behavior") due to the (guaranteed) mod 2^n-behavior, but only **if** the "n" is specified (as in `uint32_t` - it's not the case for `unsigned int`). Any attempt to define "general arithmetic" on unsigned integers could only be defined on the sized types, and while this could be possible, it would probably be of very limited use, maye counterintitive, and certainly not trivial to generalize for other (non-integral) types.