# Is this a proper use of C++20 concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a simple `Vec3<T>` class, and I would like to update it using C++20 concepts (Clang 10.0.0 with -std=c++20). The new version looks something like this:

```
template <typename T> concept Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;
template <typename T> concept FloatingPoint = std::is_floating_point_v<T>;

template <Arithmetic T> struct Vec3 {
  T x, y, z;

  /* operator overloading, etc.. */
  
  void normalize() requires FloatingPoint<T>;
};
```

Is that a proper use of C++20 concepts? The [core guideline T11](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rt-std-concepts) recommends using standard concepts as much as possible, but I couldn't find the ones I wanted in the [list of C++ named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req), nor in the `<concepts>` header file. Is this because my concepts are too specific, and shouldn't be concepts at all in the first place?

My original code uses a mix of `static_assert` and SFINAE to get to the end result.

Comment: [`std::floating_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/floating_point)

Comment: Thanks. Any reason `std::is_floating_point` got its concept and not `std::is_arithmetic`?

Comment: Not thoroughly orthogonally defined feature? Honestly, there's a whole bunch of features in C++ that have been implemented in a woefully incomplete fashion. It allows the language to have a few more features at the cost of you having to remember all the special cases...

Comment: Btw, consider making `normalize()` a free function with `Vec3<T>&` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We already have a concept for a floating point type, it is [`std::floating_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/floating_point). The absence of `std::arithmetic` seems to be an oversight and has already been noted, see [N4844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4844.pdf), page 50:

> **US 193**. C++20 lacks a concept for arithmetic types. This omission is surprising, as this is a fairly common use case. For example, suppose I wish to write a function that squares a number. Pre C++20, I might write:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> auto square(T x) {return x * x;}
> ```
>
> In C++20, it would seem natural to be able to write:
>
> ```
> auto square(std::arithmetic auto x) {return x * x;}
> ```
>
> However, such a standard library concept is missing! Instead, we must write the more verbose:
>
> ```
> template <typename T> requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
> auto square(T x) {return x * x;}
> ```
>
> Proposed change:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> concept arithmetic = is_arithmetic_v<T>;
> ```

But the question of how `std::arithmetic` should be defined is not that easy as it might seem to be. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067259/will-there-be-a-concept-for-arithmetic-types-in-c-standard-library). As **Barry** noted in the comment, that proposed change was [rejected](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/191).

Comment: That NB comment was [rejected](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/191)