# How to use c++20 concepts on classes

Tags: c++, constraints, c++20

I'm wondering why I can use

```
#include <concepts>
template<std::floating_point T> 
void f();
template<std::integral T> 
void f();
```

but not:

```
#include <concepts>
template<std::floating_point T> 
struct Point
{};

template<std::integral T> 
struct Point
{};
```

error: declaration of template parameter 'class T' with different constraints

Are c++20 concepts only available for functions?

Comment: You are redeclaring Point

Comment: You may want to look at this post on a related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067259/will-there-be-a-concept-for-arithmetic-types-in-c-standard-library

Comment: `struct f();` ? That's ill- formed unless I miss something.

Comment: struct f(); was a typo

Answer (score 2):

Concepts are available for class templates. Concept-based overloading is not - you still can have only one class template of a given name, just like before.

You can use concepts for specialization though.

Comment: How can I then use concepts for specialization? (if not the template class itself)

Comment: @SteffenRoeber [like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45d441a01cd32f1c)

Answer (score 2):

Template functions support both overloading and specialization.  Template classes only support specialization.

So in your `f` case, there are two independent overloads of `f`; you can have more than one template function with the same name, they overload.  In the class case, there are two different template classes with the same name, which is not allowed.

On the other hand, template specialization for classes is stronger than function template specialization.

```
#include <concepts>
template<class>
struct Point;
template<std::floating_point T> 
struct Point<T>
{};

template<std::integral T> 
struct Point<T>
{};
```

so the above does what you probably want.

Comment: Cool, that is what I was looging for. Unfortunately msvc does not accept following 

'''
#include <concepts>
template<typename T>
class c2DLine;

template<std::floating_point T>
class c2DLine<T>
{
  void f();
};

template<std::integral T>
class c2DLine<T>
{
    void f();
};

template<std::floating_point T>
void c2DLine<T>::f()
{

}

template<std::integral T>
void c2DLine<T>::f()
{
    
}
'''

Comment: @SteffenRoeber https://godbolt.org/z/z38EE5381 -- latest gcc, msvc, clang all compile the code I provided.  Your code looks like a different (if related) question than you asked above.  Use the [Ask Question] button to get help on it.