# Why does C++ have no std::invocable_r concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, language-design, c++-concepts

C++20 added concepts, and the standard library includes quite a few of them. One concept in particular caught my eye: [std::invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) which validates that a functor can be invoked with a set of arguments.

`std::invocable` is just syntactic sugar for `std::is_invocable`. However, the standard library further defines `std::is_invocable_r` which tests whether a functor can be invoked with a set of arguments, but also that it returns a certain type once invoked. There are also `nothrow` versions of both of these utilities. However, there are no equivalent concepts defined in the standard.

Is there a reason the standard does not define these concepts, or was it just an oversight? Is there perhaps some minutia that a casual reader did not pick up on that made the committee decide not to include these?

Comment: `std::is_invocable_r` doesn't test that a functor returns a specific type R. It tests that the return type is convertible to R. I suspect the rationale here would be the same for having `std::same_as` and `std::convertible_to` in the final design of concepts. I.e. both are valid, so the standard doesn't arbitrarily pick one, letting us choose when needed.

Answer (score 13):

The design approach of the concepts library is much more minimalistic than that of type traits. For example, there is no `std::arithmetic` concept to match the `std::is_arithmetic` trait. This has two reasons:

1. It can be trivially constructed from `std::is_arithmetic`, or from `std::integral` and `std::floating_point`.
2. It is unclear which of these constructions should be preferred.

See also: [*Will there be a concept for arithmetic types in C++ standard library?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58067259/5740428)

#### Issues with `std::invocable` and convenience concepts in general

A similar problem exists with `std::invocable` and its `_r` and `nothrow` variants. You can trivially construct a concept like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
concept invocable_r = invocable<T, Args...> && requires (Args&&... args) {
    { invoke(forward<Args>(args...)) } -> convertible_to<R>;
};
```

However, it is not so clear that this is the definitive implementation. You could also construct it in terms of `std::invoke_r`, and it's unclear whether `std::convertible_to` should still be used then.

In summary, the concepts library does not include concepts with the following issues:

1. The concept can be easily constructed from others, so it is merely there for convenience. This includes `nothrow` variants, `_r` variants, disjunctions like `std::arithmetic` etc. The user can just make these themselves.
2. There are multiple possible implementations, and it isn't perfectly clear which one should make it into the standard library. Keep in mind that the exact way a concept is defined can make it more constrained than another concept, so implementation details matter.

Note that concepts standardization was largely driven by the ranges library, and `std::invocable_r` is not essential to constraining ranges. `std::invoke` is used by [`std::indirect_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirect_result_t) in [`std::indirectly_writable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_writable).

#### The difficulty of standardizing a proposal

Last but not least, remember that standardizing any language feature is a difficult task. The slimmer a proposal, the easier it is to get it through the committee. If someone made a proposal nowadays that provides such convenience concepts, there is a good chance that it would find success, however, it would have been a difficult task back in the day which would have increased the size of the proposal ([*P9898: Standard Library Concepts*](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0898r2.pdf)) considerably.

Comment: "The user can just make these themselves." Wouldn't it be desirable to have a new C++ programmer to be able to use concepts as an abstraction layer, without having to understand the underlying (and less intuitive) C++11 metaprogramming library? The other points make a lot of sense.

Comment: @TooTone yeah, sure. There is benefit in having additional convenience concepts, even if the implementation is relatively simple. That's why I've said that a proposal for convenience concepts could likely find success. It was just too much effort with too few returns to standardize it back in the day.

Comment: One could also imagine an _external_ (header-only) library providing convenience concepts; not everything needs to be part of the _Standard_ library.